# Check if column exists, if not, add in MySQL through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm using the following code to check if the column exists, and if it doesn't, add it:

```
mysql_query("select $column from $table") or mysql_query("alter table $table add $column varchar (20)");
```

But there's no change in the database. Any suggestions why?

P.S. The database is connected.

Comment: ^ if that's the case, all the more reason to ask why there's no change.

Comment: FOR THE LOVE OF /dev/null ... dont use the PHP mysql legacy api

Comment: Actually no, `mysql_query` returns false on error.

Comment: so just be like `if (!mysql_query("select $column from $table")) mysql_query("alter table $table add $column varchar (20)");`

Comment: Tried that too. No changes to the database. @DaveChen

Comment: What are the values of `$column` and `$table`?

Comment: Using `OR` in this place is utter nonsense. A query that does not return any records is _not_ a failed query.

Comment: It's surprising how in 1 line of code you managed to commit so many atrocities against programming, common sense and what not. I sincerely hope you're using that code for the purposes of learning / testing / having fun.

Comment: Yea, I just started learning programming in PHP. Still getting there. This is indeed for learning purposes, thanks for the heads up. I didn't even know that PDO existed till now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change your SQL to...

```
//THIS IS BETTER BUT DONT USE THIS
$qry = "ALTER IGNORE TABLE {$table} ADD {$column} VARCHAR(20);"
```

Instead use PHP PDO or MySQLi with prepared statements.
Instead of that legacy horror with concatinated unescaped strings.

**MySQLi Solution:**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($cfg->host, $cfg->user, $cfg->password, $cfg->db);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo 'Connect failed: ', $mysqli->connect_error, '" }';
    exit();
}

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("ALTER IGNORE TABLE ? ADD ? VARCHAR(20);")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $table, $column);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: Are you sure? Doesn't `bind_param` make this query like `ALTER IGNORE TABLE "tableName" ADD "fieldName" VARCHAR(20);`?

Comment: Why worry about the case sensitivity of the table-/field-name?

Comment: No no, I mean quotes `ALTER IGNORE TABLE "tableName" AD...` instead of `ALTER IGNORE TABLE tableName AD...`

Comment: I understand the confusion, going to fix it.

Comment: `IGNORE` only applies to keys though... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html#idm47658597150496

That said, qisho's solution is the one i'll be upvoting

Answer (score 3):

```
$r=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SHOW columns from '".$table."' where field='".$column."'"));
if ($r==0){
    mysql_query("alter table $table add $column varchar (20)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For msqli users

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename LIKE 'keyword");
$exists = (mysqli_num_rows($result))?TRUE:FALSE;
```